# windowsphone scroll item one by one

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, scrollviewer, loopingselector

I have a vertical list of controls,I wanna show every single control at each touch move,
fist,I listen ManipulationDelta event and change image translation y,like this,
xaml,

```
            <Grid ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta">
                <UserControl/>
                <UserControl/>
                ...
                <UserControl RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <UserControl.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transfom" TranslateY="604"/>
                    </UserControl.RenderTransform>
                </UserControl>  
            </Grid>
```

code behind,

```
    private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        this.transfom.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    }
```

when the ManipulationCompleted ,move the usercontrol to the current view ,just like the loopingselector did.
but it behave not good enough(compare with the ScrollViewer's smooth scrooling,it sucks).

Then I try to work on the ScrollViewer,I have to stop the scrollviewer's own scrolling,two ways,IsHitTestVisible=False or IsEnable = false.But anyway the scrollviewer how to scroll,so,I give a parent to the scrollViewer,like this,
xaml,

```
        <phone:PivotItem ManipulationDelta="scrollViewer_ManipulationDelta">
            <ScrollViewer IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <StackPanel>
                    <UserControlHeight="604" Background="DarkRed"/>
                <UserControlHeight="604" Background="DarkRed"/>
                    <UserControl Height="604"  Background="DarkBlue"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

code behind,

```
    private void scrollViewer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ManipulationDelta:" + e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y);
        this.scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
    }
```

yeah,it works awesome,BUT...
IsHitTestVisible="False" means nothing can be catched in the ScrollViewer,eg.I cann't get UserControl's tap event.
So...Is there anyways to control the ScrollViewer's scrolling and make suer the ScrollViewer is alive.